# How to call JMeter time function once per JMS Publisher sampler execution and use the resulting value in multiple places in the same sampler?

Tags: jmeter

I have a JMS Publisher sampler in which I want to use the value of the JMeter time function in 2 places (JMS properties and text body) but I need the value generated only once per sampler execution so that I can use the same value in both places of the same sampler.

The problem is that this function is called once when I put it in the JMS Properties section and a 2nd time when I put it in the request Object message text body and I get 2 slightly different values which is not what I want. I only need to use one value in both places.
This is the function call I use: `{__time(yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS)}`

Can someone please give me an idea of how I could proceed?

I was thinking that I need a preprocessor to be executed before the Publisher sampler which would give me a variable populated and then I could use that value, but I don't know which preprocessor. I was familiar with JSR223 Preprocessor usage but sadly, I can't use the JMeter function call in a JSR223 sampler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 2nd argument in the [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) where you can specify the name of JMeter Variable to store the result in.

So if you change your function call to:

```
${__time(yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS,timestamp)}
```

you will be able to refer the generated value as `${timestamp}` where required

[image]

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)